# Explain the o/p of following program

Tags: c++, c, pointers

Explain the o/p of following program.

```
int main()
{
    int a [2][3] = {5,10,15,20,25,30}; 
    int (*p) [2][3] =&a;
    printf ("%d\t", ***(p+1)); 
    printf ("%d\t", ***p); 
    printf ("%d\t", ** (*p+1));
}
```

OUTPUT:-

```
Garbage, 5,20?
```

Comment: Indent your code and make it readable

Comment: There's not much to explain; `*(p+1)` is undefined.

Answer (score 3):

`p` is a pointer to a 2D rray of size `[2][3]`.

1) `p+1` this would increment `p` to jump to the next variable of its type, which is 2D array of size`[2][3]`. Since this place has not been allocated, its going beyond the array `a`. So, its undefined behavior, so only its giving garbage value..

2) `***p` is just de-referencing the pointer and going to the first value `5`

3) To understand how the last one is working, you need to understand how array dereferencing works. `a[1][0]` actually becomes `*(*(a+1) + 0)`, and thus will give the value `20`. So, because `p` is `&a`, thus `*p` is `a`. Now replace `a` in `*(*(a+1) + 0)` with `*p`. And thats what the third answer is